# javascript function as argument - Illegal invocation. Why?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

why the following code doesn't work? it is going in Illegal invocation exception:

```
function forEach(array , action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        action(array[i]);
}
forEach([1,2,3], console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
function forEach(array , action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        action(array[i]);
    }
}
```

You can call the above as:

```
forEach([1,2,3], function(value){
    console.log(value)
});
```

OR

```
forEach([1,2,3], console.log.bind(console));
```